# What exactly do the service() method of this HttpServlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

this is my first time that I work on a Java project that use **HttpServlet**.

So I know that an **HttpServlet** is a program that run on a Web Application server and act as a middle layer between a request coming from a Web browser or other HTTP client and databases or applications on the HTTP server. So the servlet extend the competence of my application server.

I have some doubt to understand how exactly work this servlet founded into my project, into **web.xml** file I found this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">    
<web-app>

    <display-name>My Project</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.quartz.QuartzListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>    
        <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Monitoraggio</servlet-class>   
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>    
        <url-pattern>/edimon.do/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/logon.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>displaytag</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/displaytag-11.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>

</web-app>
```

So reading some documentation it seem to understand that I have to tell the servlet container (or application server) what servlets to deploy, and what URL's to map the servlets to.

In the previous case I am configuring a servlet named **edimon** implemented by the **Monitoraggio** class.

Then it is mapped the servlet to a URL or URL pattern. In this case the **edimon** servlet is mapping with the **/edimon.do/*** URL pattern. So when it is called something that match with the previous pattern the edimon servlet is performed.

Then into my **Monitoraggio** class that implement the **HttpServlet** I found the **service()** method:

```
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LoggerMDC.setup(req, res);
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC

        String service = req.getParameter("serv");

        char serviceId = Utility.getServizio(req.getParameter("serv"));

        if (checkSession(req, serviceId) == false) {
            gotoPage(ConfigurationFactory.getPropertiesPages().getProperty("pagina_errore_session"), req, res);
            return;
        }

        LoggerWatch loggerWatch = new LoggerWatch(Monitoraggio.class, Long.valueOf(System.getProperty(Constants.Keys.CONFIG_STATS_WARNING_THRESHOLD, String.valueOf(LoggerWatch.DEFAULT_WARNING_THRESHOLD))).longValue());
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
            logger.trace("lanciaServizio() | logger threshold: " + loggerWatch.getWarningThreshold());

        loggerWatch.start();
        loggerWatch.info(new StringBuffer("service() | servizio: [").append(service).append("] | service start").toString());

        String paginaDaLanciare = lanciaServizio(serviceId, req, res);
        String executionTime = loggerWatch.getInfoTime();

        //Modifica per export
        if (req.getSession().getAttribute("export") == null) {
            gotoPage(paginaDaLanciare, req, res);
        }

        loggerWatch.info(new StringBuffer("service() | servizio: [").append(service).append("] | [").append(executionTime).append("] after forward to ").append(paginaDaLanciare).toString(), true);
        loggerWatch.stop();

        req.getSession().removeAttribute("export");
        req.getSession().removeAttribute("stringaXML");
        req.getSession().removeAttribute("downbyte");

        return;
    }
```

Reading on the documentation it **receives standard HTTP requests from the public service method and dispatches them to the doXXX methods defined in this class**

So what exatly do this method? I can't understand how the servlet load the JSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you read describes what the service() method of HttpServlet does by default. Since your servlet overrides the `service()` method and provides a different implementation, it doesn't do that anymore. Instead, it does... what the code in the method does.

A servlet doesn't "load a JSP". I don't see how JSPs have any relation to the servlet code you posted. Maybe `gotoPage()` does tell the container to forward the request to a JSP. You should look at the documentation and/or code of that method to know what it does.