# Valid reason for servlet to override HttpServlet service method

Tags: java, servlets, dry

I have a few legacy Servlets overriding service method,

According to [HttpServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) docs service method shouldn't be overridden, only in specific cases:

> There's **almost** no reason to override the service method. service handles standard HTTP requests by dispatching them to the handler methods for each HTTP request type (the doXXX methods listed above).

I found several answer about service method that [calls the do methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156135/where-are-doget-dopost-methods-in-httpservlet-class-linked-to-service-meth)

> the calls to doGet(), doPost() and the other do-methods are in the HttpServlet class

It's done [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122613/what-exactly-do-the-service-method-of-this-httpservlet) and can be overriden

> Since your servlet overrides the service() method and provides a different implementation, it doesn't do that anymore. Instead, it does... what the code in the method does.

and answers that says why [**not** overide it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891975/overriding-httpservlet-service-method)

> let servlet handle other methods.

But I didn't any valid reason why to override this method, is there any case(s) ?

It seems that it may correspond to **DRY** (Don't repeat yourself) rule, so all do methods will execute same method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd *have* to override `service` if you need to handle a non-standard HTTP method, i.e. one that hasn't been dispatched to a `doXxx` method by `HttpServlet`.

As the [RFC 2616 HTTP documentation](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) says:

> The set of common methods for HTTP/1.1 is defined below. Although **this set can be expanded**, additional methods cannot be assumed to share the same semantics for separately extended clients and servers.

Your own quote even says the same, although only implicitly:

> There's almost no reason to override the `service` method. `service` handles **standard** HTTP requests by dispatching them to the handler methods for each HTTP request type (the `doXXX` methods listed above).

Implicit is that non-standard requests must be handled by overriding the method.

Comment: You mean, for example, sending methods related to WebDav as: COPY, LOCK ...?

Comment: @user7294900 Correct.